# Html hide image border

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm decorating a table with CSS, and I added arrow in order to show in which direction the data is sorted. The arrow is displayed, but there is a border around it that I can't remove. How would it be possible to remove this border using CSS ?

[image]

CSS looks like this :

```css
table>thead>tr>th.sort-desc>img {
    background: transparent url(/assets/grid_ctrl_imgs.png) no-repeat scroll -100px -67px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And the HTML of this header looks like this :

```html
<th *ngFor='let key of columns' class='sort-desc'>
                {{ key.label }} <img>
</th>
```

Comment: Will you please share the link of web page where your want to remove the border

Comment: Since it's implemented as a background-image just don't use the `img` tag at all and change `img` tag to `span`, or apply it to the `th` itself with some right padding to provide space for it since another element isn't necessary, or just add `border: 0` to your css.

Comment: Well, looks like the span did it, thank you. I didn't even need padding, it looks great. Pleas post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#class img
{
 border: none;
}
```

OR

```
attribute 
<img src="" border=0/>
```

Both work perfectly for me.

Comment: I tried both earlier, with no effect. Maybe something specific to img tags in table th tag...

Comment: Maybe it's one of the image attributes that is causing the issues?